# Setting sort indicator on CListCtrl is clearing the column title

Tags: c++, mfc, clistctrl

[image]

While setting the sort indicator on a particular column clearing that column's title.

Code Snippet

```
HDITEM headerInfo = {0};

for (int colindex = 0; colindex < n; colindex++)
{
    if (TRUE == pHDR->GetItem(colindex, &headerInfo))
    {

        headerInfo.mask = HDI_FORMAT;
    // column match?
        if (colindex == column)
        {
            if (ascending)
            {
                headerInfo.fmt |= HDF_SORTUP;
                headerInfo.fmt &= ~HDF_SORTDOWN;
            }
            else
            {
                headerInfo.fmt |= HDF_SORTDOWN;
                headerInfo.fmt &= ~HDF_SORTUP;
            }
        }
        // switch off sort arrows
        else
        {
            headerInfo.fmt &= ~HDF_SORTDOWN & ~HDF_SORTUP;
        }       
        pHDR->SetItem(colindex, &headerInfo);
    }
}
```

If I remove the `headerInfo` initialization its working fine in debug mode but its crashing in release mode.
`HDITEM` headerInfo;

Column title was Name. It's cleared after clicking on it

Comment: Is there enough space to show both the header title as well as the sorting indicator?

Comment: @IInspectable Yes, Its there

Comment: Maybe show some screen grabs ...

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Updated the Screenshot, Column title was Name, After clicking on that its got removed and added the sort indicator

Comment: Any improvement if you use `headerInfo.mask |= HDI_FORMAT;` to _append_ the flag rather than _replace_ because any existing `HDI_TEXT` specifying text title would get removed? Just an idea.

Comment: I think @acraig5075 is right about using `|=` but can't you just make use of `CMFCListCtrl::SetSortColumn`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfcheaderctrl-class?view=vs-2019#setsortcolumn You don't actually state the control you are using.

Comment: @acraig5075 Yes I tried this as well. Still the issue is there

Comment: @AndrewTruckle This issue is happening only when I initialise headerInfo to {0}

Comment: Have you tried what the other commentator suggested?

Comment: What kind of control is this? What is `pHDR`?

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou its CListCtrl

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Yes, I tried all the suggestions. But still, the issue is there

Comment: I do have some code that does this for a `CListCtrl` control (contained in a `CListView` though), but as you have already found a way to make it work it is pointless to post it. One suggestion, you do set the indicator for the column clicked and remove it from all the others, but this could be optomized a little, ie remove it from the previously clicked column only.

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou Sure, I will do it. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

At last I got the answer, we have to apply the `HDI_FORMAT` before `GetItem`. If we are applying after the `GetItem`, it will clear the masked flags. I tested and it is working as expected.

```
HDITEM headerInfo = {0};
headerInfo.mask = HDI_FORMAT;

for (int colindex = 0; colindex < n; colindex++)
{
if (TRUE == pHDR->GetItem(colindex, &headerInfo))
{
    // column match?
    if (colindex == column)
    {
        if (ascending)
        {
            headerInfo.fmt |= HDF_SORTUP;
            headerInfo.fmt &= ~HDF_SORTDOWN;
        }
        else
        {
            headerInfo.fmt |= HDF_SORTDOWN;
            headerInfo.fmt &= ~HDF_SORTUP;
        }
    }
    // switch off sort arrows
    else
    {
        headerInfo.fmt &= ~HDF_SORTDOWN & ~HDF_SORTUP;
    }       
    pHDR->SetItem(colindex, &headerInfo);
}
}
```

Thank you everyone for the suggestions and input.

Comment: Well yes, you set the mask to state what items you want to get. 

Now I see that error in your original code. Well done.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few things wrong.

First, if you call `GetItem` with `headerInfo.mask` set to 0 - you are not getting anything back. For the subsequent calls it will be set to `HDI_FORMAT`, so you will be getting format info.

Second, it is not clear what do you need that `GetItem` call anyway; you don't use any of the fields. You only test that this call returns `TRUE`, but that is expected for all valid column indexes.

And last, in your `SetItem` you are stating that the `fmt` member is valid, but it doesn't contain `HDF_STRING` flag, so no text will be displayed on that item.

Comment: Calling `GetItem` is required. If you don't, the header control drops all `fmt` flags that aren't set in the subsequent call to `SetItem`. Indeed, the OP is using the `fmt` field.

Comment: @Vlad : But it is working fine in debug mode if I remove the Initialization of headerInfo

Comment: @iam: It's *not* *"working fine"* in debug mode. You just got lucky that the debug runtime fills uninitialized memory with a bit pattern (`0xCD`), that happens to have the desired bit (`HDI_FORMAT`, 0x04) set. The release runtime doesn't, and you wind up with whatever garbage happens to be in that memory location.